# What does it mean to say that FWHM is "a waveform in the Fourier region"?

Tags: waves, fourier-transform

The [full width at half maximum (FWHM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_width_at_half_maximum) is illustrated as follows:

> [image]

FWHM is commonly used in the context of electromagnetic and acoustic waves.

I have seen this described as "a waveform in the Fourier region". However, the Wikipedia article has no mention of "Fourier" at all, and simple Googling does not yield any results that address my specific question. What does it mean to say that FWHM is "a waveform in the Fourier region"? Please also demonstrate the mathematics behind this being "a waveform in the Fourier region".

---

### EDIT

[image]

Comment: I've never heard of it referred to that way.  Can you provide an example for context?

Comment: @garyp I can't remember where it was from, but it had something to do with sound waves and how their amplitude decays in space. The description also included the wavenumber, $k$. I found an image online that seems to resemble what I saw (see edit).

Comment: You have basically answered your question by adding the two graphs. Both forms are Fourier transforms of one another. If you perform a Fourier transformation on the f(x) you will get the same form as f(x).

Comment: @Viesik Can you please show me what you mean? I'm a novice to this, so what you're saying isn't clear to me.

Comment: Do you know what a Fourier transform is?

Comment: @Viesik Yes, but I haven't studied it in detail yet (I have studied Laplace transforms, though).

Comment: Well, basically it's a mathematical transformation on the function at hand that decomposes it in sine and cosine forms. The emergent function (after the transformation is carried out on f(x)) gives you the distribution of relative strengths of these sines and cosines. The height of the transform gives you the relative strengths of the contributions (with a different variable from x, in your example it's momentum, p). In your case the transform gives the same form as f(x). And that last feature is why it's called Fourier-like.

Comment: @Viesik So the pre-transformed function is the $f(x)$ in the FWHM graph, and the Fourier-transformed function is the one shown in the graph with $k$ on the $x$-axis? And so the Fourier-transformed function graph is the "waveform in the Fourier region"?

Comment: @Viesik And when you say momentum, $p$, what are you referring to? The $y$-axis of the Fourier-transformed function graph? And is this the same as the "amplitude" of the wave?

Comment: Concerning your first comment , yes.  The first one is f(x), the second one F(p). The variable p is momentum and F(p) gives the momentum distribution of the sound wave when you know how it moves in space.

Comment: If the waveform stays steady in space there is only one p. If it disperses, there are different p's and they show the same distribution as the wace itself.

Comment: @Viesik Hmm, so why are you mentioning $p$ instead of $k$? This part confuses me.

Comment: Because k and $\lamda$ form a different couple. These are the distributions of wavelengths and frequencies. Likewise, position and momentum form another pair whichcan be Foriertransforms of one another. You*can* couple the position to wavelength too. If you know the distribution of the f's (as in your example I guess (f(x) means frequencies?) Or you can couple frequency to wavelebtgh. It's a bit unclear what your function f(x)stands for.

Comment: @Viesik Oh, ok, I see what you mean. Thanks for taking the time to explain this!

Comment: Okay! Your welcome!